# Parsing PKCS10 from PKCS7 in PHP

Tags: php, windows-phone-8, mdm, phpseclib, pkcs#7

Background: I'm implementing an MDM solution for WP8, on initial enrolment, the binary security token is a base 64 encoded PKCS10 CSR.  On certificate renewal, the soap request is exactly the same, only the token type specified is "Renew" and the binary security token is a base 64 encoded PKCS7.

I am trying to obtain a PKCS10 from a PKCS7 base64 encoded string - I've tried openssl_pkcs7_verify which takes a filename for content. I'm assuming the content that is written contains the CSR.  However, I cannot get this function to succeed and eventually resorted to the following which works -

```
private function parsePKCS10( $insb64PKCS7 ) {
    $decodedPKCS7 = base64_decode( $insb64PKCS7 );

    $buffer = "";
    $b64PKCS10 = "";
    $lengthPKCS7 = strlen( $decodedPKCS7 );
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $lengthPKCS7; ++$i ) {
        $currentChar = $decodedPKCS7[ $i ];
        if ( mb_detect_encoding( $currentChar ) == "ASCII" && strlen( $currentChar ) != 0 ) {
            $buffer .= $currentChar;
        } else if ( (strlen( $currentChar ) != 0) || ($i + 1 < $lengthPKCS7 && strlen( $decodedPKCS7[ $i + 1 ] ) == 0) ) {
            if ( strlen( $buffer ) > strlen( $b64PKCS10 ) ) {
                $b64PKCS10 = $buffer;
            }
            $buffer = "";
        }
    }

    return preg_replace( '/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $b64PKCS10 ); //remove non-printable chars
}
```

I found an example online doing this in C# -

```
private static string extractPKCS10(string PKCS7blob)
        {
            SignedCms cms = new SignedCms();
            cms.Decode(System.Convert.FromBase64String(PKCS7blob));
            byte[] csr = cms.ContentInfo.Content;

            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(csr);
        }
```

Does anyone know a better way of doing this in PHP, or should I stick with my current function which does the job?

Thanks

EDIT -

I found a better solution using PHPSecLib -

```
$asn1 = new File_ASN1();
$certDump = $asn1->decodeBER( base64_decode( $cert ) );
$csr = extractPKCS10( $certDump );
print( $csr );


function extractPKCS10( $pkcs7, $parent = null ){

    $pkcs7DataOID = '1.2.840.113549.1.7.1';

    foreach( $pkcs7 as $key => $value ){
        if( $key == 'content' && $value == $pkcs7DataOID ){
            $csrBlob = $parent[1]['content'][0]['content'];
            return base64_encode( $csrBlob );
        }

        if( is_array( $value ) ){
            $pkcs10 = extractPKCS10( $value, $pkcs7 );
            if( null !== $pkcs10 ){
                return $pkcs10;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```